# repeat sound after every 5 seconds

Tags: java, android, audio, logcat

I have edited and tried many methods. Basically there is button. What i want that if i click it, it will start playing sound 'norse' again after every 5 seconds, till i click that button again. I wrote script what seems fine for me but it every time crashes :(. Here is code and errors, can you help?

```
    //BUTTON SHIT\\

    teebheli = false;
    magamine = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.norse);
    bhelitegija = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTeeHeli);
    bhelitegija.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (teebheli == false ){
                bhelitegija.setText("Lõpeta heli!");
                magamine.start();
                teebheli = true;
                }
            if (teebheli == true) {
                bhelitegija.setText("Tee heli!");
                magamine.stop();
                teebheli = false;
            }

            }

    });
    piiksumine = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                int piiksumine = 0;
                while (piiksumine < 5000) {
                    sleep(100);
                    piiksumine = piiksumine + 100;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                piiksumine.start();
            }
            }
        };
```

AND error when I click on button:

```
08-11 18:09:36.738: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1224): start called in state 0
08-11 18:09:36.738: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1224): error (-38, 0)
08-11 18:09:36.746: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1224): stop called in state 0
08-11 18:09:36.746: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1224): error (-38, 0)
08-11 18:09:36.777: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1224): Error (-38,0)
08-11 18:09:36.786: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1224): Error (-38,0)
```

Comment: damn where are you from man, can't find out what language it is :)

Comment: it's in pure Estonian :)

Comment: --> at viimane.voimalus.MainStuff.<init>(MainStuff.java:37)

Comment: .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

Comment: I made restart in code. I try different way. Not it doesnt crash but it still doesnt work :/

Answer (score 1):

You have not set a name for the `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName`.

(Off the top of my head, but try something like the following):

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, sharedPreferencesName, 
    sharedPreferencesMode, resId, readAgain);
```

Do this before you try to get shared preferences.

Put whatever you like in for the values, check the documentation if the variable names aren't clear :)

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Now you are trying to access a MediaPlayer instantiated in another thread.  You can't do this.  You need to MediaPlayer.create() and MediaPlayer.start() in the same thread.

Comment: actually, there is I think:  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager **next line** 
 .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()); I think problem might be in true false, cuz it gives nullexception or something :/?

Comment: When you try to use `getDefaultSharedPreferences`, it gives you a NullReferenceException because you have not set the default shared preferences yet.

Comment: Ok. I edited code in OP post. That should be easier method. But for some reason, it seems that it doesnt get true or false at all. What might be wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Well one implementation would be to just start an async task, and start an infinite loop, in the loop keep asking for the system time, compare the time with the initial time, if time passed is equal to five second just fire the beep.

Comment: I made restart in code. I try different way. Not it doesnt crash but it still doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of piiksumine in your Thread, whatever that means, I'd rather give the Thread and the int different names.

Also I'm not sure I understand well what is intended here, but I don't think you should start the thread in its own run() method with piiksumine.start();

Comment: but shouldn't that give loop over and over again, till it is called stop?

Comment: you should prepare the MediaPlayer before calling start();

Comment: That doesnt still fix upper error. Nothing changes :(. I think problem might be in true/false or in these... When I remove conditions, it seems to work, if i just want to send sound. But with conditions, it doesnt work. But I need conditions!

Comment: the problem is in the scope of the teebheli variable

Comment: I do not understand, didn't I set teebheli = false; ?

Comment: yes, but you declared a new View.OnClickListener() as an anonymous class, so it doesn't have access to the variable in your main app class. Try to declare it with a named class: private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

You could try using android.os.CountDownTimer instead and use long countdown. There is a method onTick()  that you could leverage to play the sound (by setting to 5 seconds for countDownInterval in constructor). You could stop it by calling cancel() the next time the button is pressed.